# Is ZedGraph library development still active? If not - are there any open source replacements?

Tags: .net, charts, zedgraph

I'm about to start working on a new .NET project where I'm going to need to put real-time data from a hardware device on a chart and I was surprised to find out that [ZedGraph development seems to have died out](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Revision_History) (last activity on the wiki is noted in late 2007). Is that true?

If so, are there any good open-source replacements for ZedGraph for .NET? Or should I roll my own? I'm considering the Microsoft charting toolkit but I'm concerned that - as with the the other commercial solutions out there - I may hit a road block if I'm going to need any non-standard features (of which there may be a few).

I should add that I've used ZedGraph in the past and that my experience was pretty good with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as you can see the last revision was in November 2007, but there were some changes in the source code in December 2008. The main developer of ZedGraph decided to close this project and run some other tasks.

But still, ZedGraph is very powerful tool, it is open-source, so you can easily change anything you need in it. I'm using it in professional software for about a year and it is great solution for me. Some time ago I was looking for any replacement, but ZedGraph was still the best tool for me, regardless it's a dead project.

So it's up to you, but I will still use ZedGraph. Maybe will try to do some modifications on my own.

Comment: Gacek: can you please answer my concern in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899542/zedgraph-license) ?

Comment: I am still using ZedGraph today, this library is definitely a masterpiece in the .NET OpenSource history.