# ZedGraph License

Tags: c#, licensing, zedgraph

I made a C# Winform application, my application briefly dealing with displaying sensors values during operating time, in addition to some other Input/Output tasks.
Let's skip the algorithm part, (nothing special to mention here).
For the display part, I decided to work with [ZedGraph library](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html) for its awesome features.

The issue: when I finished my work, and about to release it, the licensing procedures pop in my mind!! reading [this page](http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/indexeffe.html?title=ZedGraph_License) didn't remove my confusion!!

Can some experts or previous users guide me please ? do I continue my software, or I should stop everything and back to use `Charts` ?

P.S: I don't change anything in the library, I just use it as it is, so in order to run my software you need [`mySoftware.exe` and `ZedGraph.dll`] to be in the same location.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you confused about? Please explain.

I think the page you referred to has it quite clear that if you change ZedGraph, then you must submit your changes to the project. Else, no. If you are using ZedGraph as a dll in your project then you don't have to submit any changes or open the source code for your project.

> **Many people are concerned that ZedGraph license terms may require you share your proprietary code if you use ZedGraph with a commercial application. This is not the case. The LGPL only applies to ZedGraph itself**
>
> **So long as you dynamically link with ZedGraph (e.g., just reference zedgraph.dll), then your executable module is a separate work from ZedGraph and it just remains a "work that uses the library".**

I would also include zedGraph license with my product and acknowledge the author in about/help page in a WinForm application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, that's assuring, what confuses me the most is similar to what you added `"I would also include zedGraph license with my product and acknowledge the author in about/help page in a WinForm application."` ! why would you do that if it is not necessary ?

Comment: I do that as an acknowledgement towards the author of that software. Kind of my little thanks!  It's just me. Although not necessary if not asked by the author.